# How to attach horns to a character?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

Ok so I know, I probably should have extruded to make these horns now, but I made the mistake of making them both separately, It's my first time making a character in blender, so I'm quite new to all of this, anyway my question is, What should I do to combine the horns to my character?

[image]

Comment: It all depends on how you really want to do it. If you're enough having horns and character as one object only then go with Ctrl+J. If you want to attach them so they become one solid mesh then that's much more complex; possible ways are boolean (+ retopology after), manual extruding from existing geometry (kind of hacky because you probably won't ever use existing horns). If your mesh were after dyntopo I would go with continuing dyntopo. But connecting new mesh to one with already relatively clean mesh is not a trivial task.

Comment: It might be helpful top post your .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ But, as others have eluded it's better to plan ahead. This is the fun! Learn , learn , learn.

Answer (score 1):

Select Character + Horns and Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to remember is to select the character, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the horns, then go to the Toolshelf and press the button that says **Join**, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> works just fine.

Comment: Ctrl+J is the keyboard shortcut for the Join on the Toolshelf or from the Objects menu

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving the existing head mesh nodes to match the horns you have here using the "manual extruding from existing geometry" suggested by Mr Zak.  Press the Z key to toggle the faces off and select a vertex. Then press Z again to toggle the faces back on.  Move the vertex using the x,y,z axis until the vertex is just popping out of the horn you are trying to match.

This can take a few iterations and you'll want to rotate the view a lot.  Try to get the edges flowing smoothly and the vertices distributed evenly.  You will probably have to add some more edge loops in the process, but wait until you get the vertices you have where you want them.

You'll essentially be using the horns you have now as guides and toss them out later.  Or at least turn them off and save them as a reference.

Ctrl+J will logically join the elements which is not a bad thing for rendering or animating.  If you are 3D printing the model then you want a contiguous surface so the horns don't fall off (depending on your slicing software).  Some slicing software will print each "volume" with an air gap between them.